# Partial derivative at (0,0).

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by:
$$f(x,y) = \left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}l@{}}
0 & \text{if }xy = 0 \\
1 & \text{if }xy\neq0
\end{array}\right..$$
Show that both partial derivatives exist at $(0,0)$.

The way I have done this is 
$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$.

I don't know what to put at the place of $f(h,0)$ and $f(0,0)$.
Any help  will be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}(0,0):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{0-0}{h}=0$$

and now something similar for the other partial derivative

Comment: could you please tell me why should we put 0 at the place of f(h,0) ?.I am not getting this part.

Comment: It's the definition you gave! Since $\;h\cdot 0=0\;$ it must be that $\;f(h,0)=0\;$ ...